# Getting garbage in my text file with scanf

Tags: c

I am getting garbage, red null characters in my file only on `int` vars.

```
typedef struct{
 int id;
 char date[MAXSTR];
 char locale[MAXSTR];
 int numberOfDeliveries;
 int volume;
 int weight;
 }
SContact;
 void StoreInFile(SContact *register)
  {
  FILE *f = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
  if(f != NULL)
    {
      f = fopen( FILE_NAME , "a" );
      fseek(f,(long)(register->id) *sizeof(SContact), SEEK_END);
      fwrite(register, sizeof(SContact), 1, f);
      fclose(f);
    }
  else{
    printf("\nError: it wasn't possible to open the file.");
  }
}   
void Record(SContact *register)
  {
  fgets(register->date,MAXSTR,stdin);
  fgets(register->locale,MAXSTR,stdin);
  scanf( "%d", &register->numberOfDeliveries);
  scanf( "%d", &register->volume);
   scanf( "%d", &register->weight);
  }
```

Tried printing the values when they are asked to be added by the user but they are printing ok, just when it's time to store them in the file they will be stored as garbage. The `char` variables are stored ok.

Comment: What does garbage mean? What input do you provide? What output do you get? What output do you expect? How do you check file content? With a text editor? With a hex editor?

Comment: You're writing as binary, the file is not meant to be human readable.  If you want to write a text file you should use `fprintf`.

Comment: thanks, I get it now, the only question I have is about the variable numberOfDeliveries. That is reading as a long list of numbers when the input was just one number, why would that happen? the other int vars are reading ok tho

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your observations.

Comment: See my first comment.

Comment: I just noticed (not connected with your current error) that `fseek(f,(long)(register->id) *sizeof(SContact), SEEK_END);` only works if you sequentially add to the file; using `SEEK_SET` will work regardless of `register->id` order. Of course, if you switch to `fprintf()` for the integers you'll need a different approach.

Comment: Also the values you are writing in each string from `strlen(register->date) + 1` to `MAXSTR` characters will be *uninitialized*. While as long as you read `MAXSTR` back in -- you will get your string back, but if you attempt to examine the file, the contents will look garbled for each string in the range between the nul-terminating character and end of the array. (that's if you don't initialize with, e.g. `SContact sc = { .id = 0 };` or allocate storage with `calloc()`.)